# How to filter Firebase reading

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a beginner and I am developing a scheduler salon at Firebase.

The scheduler keeps customer information such as name, phone number, date. Within the scheduling node, there is a node relating to the status of service, it makes it impossible for two clients to mark the same time. For this, I need to access the regarding the status node and check if the value is equal to "ocupado" (occupied) or "desocupado" (unoccupied). If the value is equal to "ocupado" (occupied), there must be return an error message. If the value is equal to "desocupado" (unoccupied), the client can make the schedule at this time.

Comment: Sorting and filtering is covered here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data If you're having trouble making that work in your app, share the minimum code and JSON (as text, no screenshots please) that reproduce that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Just acess val(), for example:

    var ref = firebase.database().ref("db/scheduler");
    ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
        var check = snapshot.child("firstTime").val();
        var returnMsg = '';
        if(check == "occupied"){
            returnMsg = "error";
        }else{
            returnMsg = 'open';
        }
        console.log(returnMsg);
    })
```